# Swift segue to xib file programmatically

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xib

I need to load a xib file from a navigation bar button item. I have to do this outside the storyboard because the same button item changes depending if the user is logged in or not. It reads "Login/Register" if a user is not logged in and goes to a login xib file and if a user is logged in it reads "Add Story" and goes to a add story xib file.

Comment: You could get around this by having two identical buttons on top of each other in your storyboard with different `IBOutlet`s and different text; set `.hidden` on the one that is not currently supposed to be shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, use an `IBOutlet` to create a var of type `UIBarButtonItem` and an action method for the button. You can then access the button programmatically to update it's label (logged in/out) when the view appears. You can do both of these by control-dragging (or right-click drag) from the button in the storyboard to the swift file.

In the storyboard, setup two segues that go to different views (i.e. "LoginSegueIdentifier" and "AddStorySegueIdentifier". Inside the action method, check if the user is logged in or not. Depending on the result, perform a segue with an the identifier matching the segue identifier.

To Login...

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("LoginSegueIdentifier", sender: self)
```

To Add story

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("AddStorySegueIdentifier", sender: self)
```

Hope this helps. Let me know if you have any questions.

UPDATE: To clarify, this is pretty common (at least in my experience) and you can definitely achieve this with storyboards.